# Encrypt string with the python standard libraries

Tags: python, string, encryption

**Some Info:**

While this question is repeated multiple times on StackOverflow and, when googled, brings up many answers; neither of these were fully the answer I was looking for. I have seen answers which use libraries like PyCrypto etc. but none of that helped.

**The question:**

I am looking for a simple way to encrypt a string in python3 using only the default libraries. I was thinking of, for example, making python replace all the letters in the string with a number or a different letter. Below is what I was thinking of, except it's not actual python code. If someone could make it work in python (and possibly shrink it a little) I would be very grateful.

**The Code (Not really):**

```
def encrypt():
  for letter in string:
    if letter = 'a':
      letter.change_to('123')
    if letter = 'b':
      letter.change_to('133')
    if letter = 'c':
      letter.change_to('124')
    if letter = 'd':
      letter.change_to('143')
    # And so on... #
```

**NOTE:** I would also appreciate if you included a way to decrypt the string if you use a different method to the one above because I am still learning and might not understand how your method works.

-Thank you all in advance :)

**EDIT:** I was asked to write why I don't want to use any external libraries. It is because I want to encrypt data I send from a client program to a server program. The client will likely run on multiple machines and I do not want to install the required libraries (or make my users do it) on all the machines.

Comment: *I have seen answers which use libraries like PyCrypto etc. but none of that helped.* You need to tell us then **why those answers didn't help** before adding to the body of questions. How is your question different? Don't just say *I researched*. **Share** that research.

Comment: have you checked `rot13` codec?

Comment: "I was thinking of, for example, making python replace all the letters in the string with a number or a different letter." -- ???! This is not encryption.

Comment: What you are doing is called a *substitution cypher*. See https://inventwithpython.com/hacking/chapter17.html for the first tutorial I found that mentions this. If you are going to attempt to do encryption on your own, then *at the very least* educate yourself about what encryption *is*.

Comment: @duskwuff Well, It makes the contents of the message unreadable and this is the desired effect, whatever you call it.

Comment: `encrypted = string[::-1]`

Comment: @duskwuff: sure it is, it's a substitution cypher. There is no claim here that this is *strong* encryption.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I shall update my question so that it states why I don't want to use any external libraries.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Strictly speaking, without a key it isn't a cipher. It's just a weird thing you can do to a string. :)

Comment: @duskwuff: the key is right there. `a` maps to `123`, `b` to `133`, etc. That mapping *is the key*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Kerckhoffs's principle holds that any cryptographic cipher should have a _changeable_ key -- it shouldn't be inherent to the cipher.

Comment: @duskwuff: yet historically, plenty of encryption systems used fixed substitutions embodied in physical devices. Think scytale sticks, or a one-time pad. Just because one pseudo implementation of an algorithm hardcoded the key doesn't mean that they can't swap out the key, it just takes a bit more work, the **algorithm** is still the same. However, we are grossly digressing here. Comments are not there for philosophical discussions about cryptographic definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here's a version of what you want using the chr() and ord() functions, which are related to a topic called ASCII. (A good thing to learn about)

```
def encrypt(originalString):
    encryptedString = ""
    for letter in originalString:
        encryptedString += str(ord(letter))+"*"
    return encryptedString[:-1]

def decrypt(encryptedString):
    decryptedString = ""
    for codeNumber in encryptedString.split("*"):
        decryptedString += chr(int(codeNumber))
    return decryptedString


s = "The crow flies at midnight"
t = encrypt(s)
u = decrypt(t)

print(s)
print(t)
print(u)
```

Output:

The crow flies at midnight
    84*104*101*32*99*114*111*119*32*102*108*105*101*115*32*97*116*32*109*105*100*110*105*103*104*116
    The crow flies at midnight

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for despite the (according to some) not clear enough wording of my question. Thank you for this simple and straightforward answer.

Comment: You're welcome! I do hope the data isn't too sensitive you're encrypting with this though, as this is VERY easy to break into if you can see the stream.

Comment: Nope, most likely it will never be needed. It's just that the program I'm making is supposed to send commands to a server. If anyone attempts to send a plaintext command from a fake client, it will not be read as a command then. Also, isn't ASCII just a way of encoding text?

Comment: @user9123 What you are intending on using this for is so ridiculously insecure that I cringed when I read your comment.  Not trying to be mean, just trying to educate.  The answer to this problem is to use TLS and a proper authentication method.  What you are doing is really laughable and provides no security at all.

Comment: It's only a program that is running for, say, 2 minutes at a time. It is also not designed to have full control over everything. I know it is insecure but it's only in testing phase now and by the end, it will be much more secure @Luke Park